# Scatterplot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want a 2x2 scatterplot matrix of the data in the file scatter.dat:

```
0.5334437   0.4824717
0.6848940   0.6865826
0.5818373   0.6335347
0.5465202   0.5290712
```

The following code works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{scatter.dat}\myscatter
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt, vertical sep=0pt,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,yticklabels at=edge left},
      height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,
    ]

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=0,y index=0] {\myscatter};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=0,y index=1] {\myscatter};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=1,y index=0] {\myscatter};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot+[only marks] table[header=false,x index=1,y index=1] {\myscatter};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would prefer an automatic version with loops for larger scatter plot matrices by modifying the code from above as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{scatter.dat}\myscatter
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt, vertical sep=0pt,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,yticklabels at=edge left},
      height=3.5cm,width=3.5cm,
    ]

    \foreach \columnA in {0,...,1} {
      \foreach \columnB in {0,...,1} {
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot+[only marks] 
          table[header=false,x index=\columnA,y index=\columnB]
          {\myscatter};
      }
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, compiling this code with pdflatex yields the following error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** A much more elegant way is to make use of the fact that the `groupplots` library knows the current row and column and the total number of plots. The counters have to be made available first by defining new names without`@`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentrow}{\the\pgfplots@group@current@row}
\newcommand{\currentcolumn}{\the\pgfplots@group@current@column}
\newcommand{\totalplots}{\pgfplots@group@totalplots}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{scatter.dat}\myscatter
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt, vertical sep=0pt,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,yticklabels at=edge left},
      height=5cm,width=5cm,xmin=0.5
    ]


    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\totalplots} {
    \nextgroupplot
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\currentcolumn-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\currentrow-1}

        \addplot+[only marks] 
          table[header=false,x index=\x,y index=\y]
          {\myscatter};
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

The way without the groupplots counters:

In this case you need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{<list>}{<commands>}` to make sure that the looping variable is passed to the commands expanded, otherwise all commands end up executing with the same value of the looping variable. Unfortunately, `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` can not be nested, so you need to make do with a single looping variable that you split up inside the loop.

In my code below, you just need to adjust the values of variables `\a` and `\b` if you need other setups. It's not quite as intuitive as the nested loops, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{scatter.dat}\myscatter
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt, vertical sep=0pt,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,yticklabels at=edge left},
      height=5cm,width=5cm
    ]
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\b{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\c{\a+\b}

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\c} {
    \nextgroupplot
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{mod(#1-1,\a)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{floor((#1-1)/\b)}

        \addplot+[only marks] 
          table[header=false,x index=\x,y index=\y]
          {\myscatter};
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: scatterplots with pgfplotsinvokeforeach]

Comment: Thanks, the error disappeared! I can see the scatter plot matrix having 2 by 2 scatterplots. The scatterplot matrix is almost perfect except of the data shown: Every plot shows the correlation of the first column to itself. It seams that \columnA and \columnB are 0 all the time.

Comment: @Chris: Ah yes, sorry for that, you need `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in this case. I've changed my answer.

Comment: For LaTeX Beamer you will need [fragile].

Comment: The way without the groupplots counters arranges the scatterplots in wrong order for largar scattor plot matrices than 2 by 2.