# \foreach in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

My final goal is to create a groupplot with 10*10 figures. I here have reduced the problem so that it will be easier to explain. First, I have created some dummy data which I store in `test.txt` and it looks like this:

```
a         b     c         d
1     0.5837    0.8208    0.7949
2     0.1267    0.8644    0.3532
3     0.2717    0.0858    0.0287
4     0.7836    0.7564    0.3105
5     0.2431    0.3875    0.5209
6     0.2896    0.4468    0.9460
7     0.8155    0.7873    0.5724
8     0.8039    0.2818    0.3114
9     0.6091    0.4700    0.3280
10    0.1231    0.1983    0.6527
```

What I want to do now is to create a row of three figures, plotting columns 2-4 against column 1. Since my final figure will be quite large, I want to do this using the `\foreach` command. Just to see what I want to do, the following code creates what I want (usingthe `test.txt` file):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 1}, height=5cm,width=5cm]
\pgfplotstableread{test.txt} \mydata;
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = 1]   {\mydata};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = 2]   {\mydata};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = 3]   {\mydata};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem occurs when I try to write the `groupplot` section of the code with the aid of `\foreach`, i.e. replacing `\begin{groupplot} ... \end{groupplot}` by

```
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=3 by 1}, height=5cm,width=5cm]
    \pgfplotstableread{test.txt}\mydata;
    \foreach \yindex in {1,2,3} 
        \nextgroupplot 
        \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = \yindex]   {\mydata};
\end{groupplot}
```

**First question:** It looks like it should work (and it did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/using-addplot-and-foreach-in-pgfplot)), but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

**Second question:** How can I access the headers in the loop? That is, if I want to let the titles for each plot be b, c and d, respectively, can I do this using the loop variable? In this case, doing everything manually is feasible, but with 100 figures, it's not.

**Third question:** In generalizing this to my 10*10 final figure, I ran into some issues. In each groupplot, I actually want to plot three lines (the main line plus error bands). My initial idea was to have three text files with data and then use three `\pgfplotstableread{}`. But that seems to not work, as it appears to only being able to handle one at a time. I could create one big data file, with columns being in blocks of three. So in groupplot 1, I would like to plot column 1 (lower bound), column 2 (median), column 3 (upper bound). That means I would have to work a little with the looping variable and do some multiplications and additions with it. How do I do this? For example, the lower bounds would have column indexes given by something like `y index = (#1-1)*3+1`, but that multiplication and addition does not seem to work like I want it to. With the looping variable `\yindex` I guess it could work, but that I couldn't get up and running (see the comments). **This is now resolved using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15112/scatterplot-with-pgfplots).**

Comment: You can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,2,3}{
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = #1]   {\mydata};
}    `. What about titles? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You're missing the `{}` around the commands that should be repeated. As it stands, it only invokes `\nextgroupplot` three times.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, I'll try it. For the titles, I mean that I could in my non-looping example easily just write `\nextgroupplot[title=b]` for the first plot, `\nextgroupplot[title=c]` for the second and so on. But could I possibly write this as `\nextgroupplot[title=\mydata{1, \yindex+1}]`. I know that this would not work, but what I mean is that I want to extract the plot title from the text file as well. `\mydata{1, \yindex+1}` would then, ideally (even though it doesn't work), give me the 1,2 element of `\mydata`, which is b, which is what I want to use for the title for the first plot.

Comment: @HarishKumar I tried it now, and it works like a charm. Thank you! @TomBombadil, where would I put these missing braces? I tried `\foreach \yindex in {1,2,3} {\nextgroupplot \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = \yindex]   {\mydata};}` but that doesn't work. I also tried `{\foreach \yindex in {1,2,3} \nextgroupplot \addplot [thick]  table [x index = 0, y index = \yindex]   {\mydata};}`to no avail.

Comment: @hejseb: The first version is the correct one. But I don't know why it doesn't work then.

Comment: @hejseb: You can use `\pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{#1}\of{\mydata}\to{\colname} \nextgroupplot[title=\colname]` to access the column name. But weirdly, that leads to titles _c, d, b_ for me, instead of _b, c, d_ ?

Comment: @TomBombadil Strange, but that seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it working properly. I added a third question to my post, because I ran into some problems when implementing this.